# Load image using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the current code of my HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL='http://google.com'" /> 
</head>

<body>

<script>
var image = document.images[0];
var downloadingImage = new Image();
downloadingImage.onload = function(){
    image.src = this.src;   
};
downloadingImage.src = "http://example.com/pixel";
</script>

<script>
window.location = "http://google.com";
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

This part of the code should be using Javascript to load an image:

```
var image = document.images[0];
var downloadingImage = new Image();
downloadingImage.onload = function(){
    image.src = this.src;   
};
downloadingImage.src = "http://example.com/pixel";
```

This is being done to verify is a user has javascript enabled or not. We direct visitors to specific advertisers and certain ones require that Javascript be enabled. The pixel that's being loaded is so we can track fraudulent traffic from third-party vendors that try to send millions of bot hits using stuff like curl.

The amount of users with javascript enabled is slightly lower than I expected and I'm not trying to debate the amount.  But does anyone see anything wrong with this code?

It's my understanding that javascript loads in order, so the image should be loaded in a browser before the user is redirected, correct?  And do you see anything wrong in the code that I guess would cause it to not load in certain browsers?

Comment: why would you want to direct them away from your site just on the basis of disabled javascript? surely it would be better to cater to their security concerns and provide a version that requires no JS? This is afterall the reason most people disable it.

Comment: Because it has nothing to do with catering to their security.  We direct visitors to specific advertisers and certain ones require that Javascript be enabled.  The pixel that's being loaded is so we can track fraudulent traffic from third-party vendors that try to send millions of bot hits using stuff like curl.

Comment: It's my understanding that javascript loads in order, so the image should be loaded in a browser before the user is redirected, correct? -- I think like this the request to load the image will start first yes, but this will happen in the background. It's possible that the redirect is then executed before the image request is completed - depending on the browser.

Comment: Hmm would there be a way to merge the 2 javascript snippets so this doesn't happen?

Comment: You can do all redirects from the javascript rather than using the meta tag to refresh. This would mean you would redirect at your command and not on a timer.

Comment: If you have your image downloaded as a binary, you could call `btoa()` to get it into base64, then you can convert that base64 into a data-uri with a data uri prefix such as `let data_uri = "data:image/png;base64,"+btoa_data;` which can be assigned to anything that takes a image-url including an Image object.

Answer (score 1):

While the script is executed in order, the loading of images is non-blocking.  As a result, setting the `image.src` to something does not wait for that image to load before moving on.  You need to determine when you'd like to be redirected, and place that code inside the image's `onload` function.  Try this:

1. Wrap your refresh tag in `<noscript></noscript>` (only valid for html5)
2. Modify your code to this:

   ```
   <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
           <title>Example</title>
           <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
           <noscript>
               <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL='http://google.com'" /> 
           </noscript>
       </head>
       <body>
           <img src="//example.org/pixel1">
           <script>
               var image = document.images[0];
               var downloadingImage = new Image();
               downloadingImage.onload = function(){
                   console.log('downloadImage loaded');
                   image.onload = function(){
                       console.log('image loaded');
                       window.location = "http://google.com";
                   }
                   image.src = this.src;   
               };
               downloadingImage.src = "//example.com/pixel2";
           </script>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```